# timeout warn happened during alias process

Tags: elasticsearch

Our system have two indexes(ex:data1 & data2), and have a alias(ex:data).
[alias:data] is changed between [index:data1] and [index:data2] every 10m.
Then index which dont have the alias, will be recreate by another program just like delete → mapping → set data → wait for alias change.

alias change java code(data2):

```
IndicesAliasesRequestBuilder aliasRequest = ElasticUtils.getTransportClientInstance().admin().indices().prepareAliases()
    .addAlias("data2", "data")
    .removeAlias("data1", "data");
IndicesAliasesResponse aliasResponse = aliasRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

My question:
In normally, process time of alias is <1s, but occasionally(once a week?) timeout warn happen.ES server log:

```
[2016-06-13 09:12:33,333][WARN ][cluster.service          ] [Node#2] cluster state update task [index-aliases] took 40.1s above the warn threshold of 30s
```

Does anyone know why this problem happens occasionally? Thanks.

ps:we are using elasticsearch_2.2.